# UI patterns for data composition

Tags: design-patterns, interface

More specifically, I would like to create an interface which

1. Takes input from one or multiple sources.
2. Makes it possible to process on these inputs
3. Provides a way to capture the output.

One way I figured would be using something similar to Blender's composition nodes (https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=blender+compositing)

Now to my question,

- Are there any other recognized UI patterns which solves what I am attempting?
- Is there a more general name for the pattern used for Blender's composition nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Takes input from one or multiple sources.
>
> Makes it possible to process on these inputs
>
> Provides a way to capture the output.

This sounds general enough to be simply *computer programming*, but it sounds like you want a GUI visual based programming language.  There are many [visual programming languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=visual%20imperative%20language&aq=f&oq=visual%20imperative%20language&aqs=chrome.0.57j62.7084&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sugexp=ckwqrh&gs_rn=8&gs_ri=psy-ab&gs_mss=visual%20programm%20language&tok=Jtm1toSP6Pt56xn_5YSo2A&pq=visual%20imperative%20language&cp=16&gs_id=12&xhr=t&q=visual%20programming%20language&es_nrs=true&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=visual%20programmi%20language&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44697112,d.cGE&fp=4eeaa83fb1967c93&biw=1268&bih=771).  Many of these VPLs, particularly of the dataflow variety, that could satisfy those 3 requirements you list, but **none of them well established outside of rather specialized communities**.

Here are some examples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb483088.aspx

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/

http://www.zaluum.com/

http://www.codemorphis.com/

http://osw.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any other recognized UI patterns which solves what I am
>   attempting?

Could your interface be related to Generative Design and [Generative Modelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_Modelling_Language)?

Another CAD Program [Grasshopper](http://www.grasshopper3d.com) for Rhino3D uses this type of interface as well.

> Is there a more general name for the pattern used for Blender's
>   composition nodes?

I don't know the pattern's name of such an interface but I can see how it could easily allow users to use any combination of "1." and "2." multiple times without a sequential order. As per your "3." It's up to you to find the best way to represent the output for your users.